# Appending a new path to VIMRUNTIME variable

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I have developed a custom syntax highlighter and syntax detector for a specific file extension. Currently, it works fine when I manually copy the necessary files to `$HOME/.vim/syntax` and `$HOME/.vim/ftdetect` directories. However, I would prefer not to modify the home directories directly.

Instead, I would like to append a new directory path to the VIMRUNTIME variable. This way, when I open Vim, it would first search for syntax files in the new directory and then fall back to the default path.

However, when I set the `VIMRUNTIME` variable with the additional path, Vim is no longer able to locate the default Vim files.

Is there a solution or workaround that would allow me to achieve my desired setup without losing access to the default Vim files?

Comment: Make it a plugin, i.e. put your 2 directories in a subdirectory of `~/.vim/plugin/` — they will be loaded automatically. See https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#load-plugins

Comment: that's a good idea but I don't want to copy or touch any file outside of the build directory. my ideal solution is to have syntax highlighter files under my build directory and set a variable or something during the build process so if the user update run a command which only updates his environment variables everything continues working

Comment: `~/.vim` *is* where you are supposed to do your customization.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I'm just asking since I'm wondering if there is any other solution...!

Comment: What's the part on "losing access to the default Vim files"? Not sure if this is what you meant but you can `:source` the default config from your `vimrc` as explained in `:help defaults.vim`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your plugin looks like this:

```
/foo/bar/ftdetect/xyz.vim
/foo/bar/syntax/xyz.vim
```

it is *possible* to do something like:

```
$ vim --cmd "set runtimepath^=/foo/bar"
```

which will prepend `/foo/bar` to `:help 'runtimepath'`.

Note that, if your plugin contains an `after` directory, you will need to *append* it too:

```
$ vim --cmd "set runtimepath^=/foo/bar" --cmd "set runtimepath+=/foo/bar/after"
```

But I would suggest you simply keep your plugin under `~/.vim`. That directory is *really* yours and it is the proper place for any customization.

Now, if you absolutely want to package your vim scripts as part of some larger project, then you will need to instruct your users to add something like this to their `vimrc`:

```
set runtimepath^=/foo/bar
set runtimepath+=/foo/bar/after
```

But again, it seems preferable to submit your support scripts to Vim so that they are included in the default distribution.